# How do I change the default height of a BottomSheetDialog?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-support-design

I've been using the new BottomSheetDialog added in [Support Library 23.2](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html), but I want to change the default height of the dialog. I know it probably has to do with the `behavior_peekHeight` attribute which controls the initial height, but how do I set that in the `BottomSheetDialog` when I don't have direct access to the `BottomSheetBehavior`?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can set a `bottomSheetDialogTheme` in your Activity, overriding the `bottomSheetStyle` attribute's `behavior_peekHeight`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
  <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/AppBottomSheetDialogTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="AppBottomSheetDialogTheme"
       parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
  <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/AppModalStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="AppModalStyle"
       parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
  <item name="behavior_peekHeight">@dimen/custom_peek_height</item>
</style>
```

This same technique can be used for other attributes as well, such as adding `<item name="behavior_hideable">true</item>` to the `AppModalStyle` to change whether the bottom sheet is hideable.

Comment: This does not work when using Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar as parent layout

Comment: I notice that behavior_peekHeight only takes effect if the value is greater than 208dp. Why is that?

Comment: @AmJay - that should be fixed in version 23.2.1. Make sure to update!

Comment: Yes 23.2.1 fixed it. Thanks!!

Comment: getting this erro: Cannot resolve symbol 'Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog'

Comment: Setting the peek height in styles does not work unless the Bottom Sheet Dialog is used inside a Coordinator Layout. The only way to set the peek height when using a BottomSheetDialogFragment is through setUpDialog(). See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38873329/6211703

Answer (score 27):

you can use `BottomSheetBehavior`in your code

```
BottomSheetDialog dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(content);
.
.
.
dialog.setContentView(view);
BottomSheetBehavior mBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from((View) view.getParent());
mBehavior.setPeekHeight(your dialog height)
dialog.show();
```

Comment: getParent() gives null

Answer (score 19):

styles.xml

```
<style name="BottomSheetDialog" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/bottomSheetStyleWrapper</item>
</style>

<style name="bottomSheetStyleWrapper" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="behavior_peekHeight">500dp</item>
</style>
```

```
BottomSheetDialog dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(this, R.style.BottomSheetDialog);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout_bottom_sheet);
dialog.show();
```

Comment: This is not working for me, the bottom sheet takes the all screen's height.

Comment: change the behavior_peekHeight

Comment: I did, obviously. but it doesn't matter what value i put.

Comment: getting this erro: Cannot resolve symbol 'Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog'

Answer (score 15):

Woks for me

```
  override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    dialog?.also {
        val bottomSheet = dialog.findViewById<View>(R.id.design_bottom_sheet)
        bottomSheet.layoutParams.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        val behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from<View>(bottomSheet)
        behavior.peekHeight = resources.displayMetrics.heightPixels //replace to whatever you want
        view?.requestLayout()
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked for me just changed to WRAP_CONTENT 
 bottomSheet.layoutParams.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT

Comment: `requestLayout()` solves the issue

Answer (score 11):

Honestly, I've got no idea why nobody has mentioned these simple ways, yet:

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    dialog.behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
    // or since com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-beta01
    (dialog as? BottomSheetDialog)?.behavior?.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED

}
//or
dialog.behavior.peekheight = YOUR_VALUE
```

Directly answering the question

> **Q**: How can I directly access the BottomSheetBehavior height?
>
> **A**: `dialog.behavior.peekheight`

Comment: BottomSheetDialog.behavior is private now

Comment: @Aguragorn as I can see it's [defined](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/708c50f8d23f195e76663daf274c6b935ddc8aef/lib/java/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetDialog.java#L226) `public`

Answer (score 6):

My bottom sheet dialog had recycler view and didn't had items to show, so it was shrinking, but let's say u want to set peek height to 85% irrespective of items present in Recyclerview or not, try this solution.

Add the following code in class which extends BottomSheetDialogFragment

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    (dialog as BottomSheetDialog).behavior.peekHeight = getBottomSheetDialogDefaultHeight()
    dialog?.let {
        val bottomSheet = it.findViewById<View>(R.id.design_bottom_sheet)
        bottomSheet.layoutParams.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    }
}

private fun getBottomSheetDialogDefaultHeight(): Int {
    val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
    (context as Activity?)?.windowManager?.defaultDisplay?.getMetrics(displayMetrics)
    return displayMetrics.heightPixels * 85 / 100
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way is inheriting `BottomSheetDialogFragment` and have control how and when you set the content view. Going up the view tree, you can get the behavior that `BottomSheetDialog` wraps up the content view. It's not really good solution, because it requires more layout passes. It is important that when the state of the bottom sheet is `STATE_HIDDEN` we have to dismiss the dialog, if we don't we clearly violate the implementation provided in the library.

After setting the peek height programmatically, content view must call `requestLayout()` which is indeed another layout pass.

```
public class CustomBottomSheetDialogFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {


    private BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback = new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
            setStateText(newState);
            if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
                dismiss();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
        }
    };

@Override
    public void setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style) {
        super.setupDialog(dialog, style);
        View contentView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.bottom_sheet_dialog_content_view, null);
        dialog.setContentView(contentView);
        mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(((View) contentView.getParent()));
        if (mBottomSheetBehavior != null) {
           mBottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback);    
           mBottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(peekHeight);
           contentView.requestLayout();
        }
}
```

Comment: At this point, you've replaced more of `BottomSheetDialog` than you are still using and should just roll your own right?

Comment: @ianhanniballake My initial intention was to bypass `BottomSheetDialog` internal instance of the `BottomSheetCallback` which simply dismisses the dialog, and have my own for more control. Having instance of the behavior can be utilized for this scenario too.

Comment: Note there is a helper method `BottomSheetBehavior.from(View)` which could simplify your logic (although it throws `IllegalArgumentException`s)

Comment: @ianhanniballake In my case, you still need to point to the view that has the behavior otherwise, `from()` method doesn't walk the tree until it finds the behavior, as you said it will throw IAE. Yeah, it tidies up the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `BottomSheetDialogFragment` and do it programatically also.

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    (dialog as? BottomSheetDialog)?.let {
      it.behavior.peekHeight = PEEK_HEIGHT
    }
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_dialog_fragement, container, false)
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using BottomSheetDialogFragment, copy and paste this code

```
private View bottomSheet;

@Override public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Dialog dialog = getDialog();
    if (dialog != null) {
      bottomSheet = dialog.findViewById(R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        bottomSheet.getLayoutParams().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
      }
      View view = getView();
      view.post(() -> {
        View parent = (View) view.getParent();
        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params =
            (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) (parent).getLayoutParams();
        CoordinatorLayout.Behavior behavior = params.getBehavior();
        BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior = (BottomSheetBehavior) behavior;
      bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(view.getMeasuredHeight());
// Here you can play with the height of the bottom sheet like pass height as- [view.getMeasuredHeight()/2]

            ((View) bottomSheet.getParent()).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
          });
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Combining Nick and litao's solution, this is a complete version of what we do:

```
 BottomSheetDialog bottomSheet = new BottomSheetDialog(context);
 View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.your_action_sheet, null);
 bottomSheet.setContentView(view);
 BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(((View) view.getParent()));
 bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(1000);
 bottomSheet.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I decided on the problem:

```
   override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val dialog = BottomSheetDialog(context)
        val view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.bottom_dialog, null)

        val heightInPixels = 500
        val params = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, heightInPixels)

        dialog.setContentView(view, params)

        return dialog
    }
```

The main part is method `setContentView(view, params)`, where you set view for your dialog and layout parameters in which you set the desired height.

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me to show BottomSheetDialog full screen(STATE_EXPANDED).I am using this in my Activity.

```
private void showBottomSheetDialog() {
        View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.your_custom_layout, null);
        BottomSheetDialog dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(NewWorkoutPlanActivity.this);
        dialog.setContentView(dialogView);

       
        FrameLayout bottomSheet = (FrameLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
        BottomSheetBehavior behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = bottomSheet.getLayoutParams();

        int windowHeight = getWindowHeight();
        if (layoutParams != null) {
            layoutParams.height = windowHeight;
        }
        bottomSheet.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);

        dialog.show();

    }

    private int getWindowHeight() {
        // Calculate window height for fullscreen use
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        return displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are extending BottomSheetDialog**Fragment**, you can do the following to get hold of BottomSheetBehavior:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    //Must add any view here, actual view will be inflated in onCreateView
    dialog.setContentView(new View(getContext()));
    //Dialog wraps view in frame layout
    View root = dialog.findViewById(R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
    //Now we have access to BottomSheetBehavior
    BottomSheetBehavior<View> behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(root);
    //Do whatever you need:
    behavior.setPeekHeight(320, true);
    behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HALF_EXPANDED);

    return dialog;
}
```

Then override onCreateView as usual:

```
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //inflate your bottom sheet layout:
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.browser_bottom_sheet, container, false);
    //Do what you need with views:
    ViewPager viewPager = root.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
                  ...........

    return root;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got one hack and used it.

If you want to do programmatically.

```
    behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View view, int i) {
            behavior.setPeekHeight(yourMinHeight);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View view, float v) {

        }
    });
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The really approach we want to achieve this is actual make the LayoutParams works. When inflating content view of the dialog, not passing the `parentView` in the dialog `Window` will make xml config of the rootView does NOT actually work.

So here is a solution:

```kotlin
val contentWidth = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
val contentHeight = 500 // px
dialog.setContentView(view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams(contentWidth, contentHeight))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to set height of DialogFragment or BottomSheetDialogFragment. The dialog will adjust its height with different screen height

```
  override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        val window = dialog?.window
        val ratio = 1.0

        if (window != null && activity != null) {
            val heightDialog = (getScreenHeight(requireActivity()) * 0.9f).toInt()
            window.setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (heightDialog * ratio).toInt())
            window.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the `BottomSheetBehavior` object from `getBehaviour()` in the `onStart()` method, then modify the peek height from there.

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    getBehavior().setPeekHeight(/* Peek Height in px */);
}
```

Comment: There's no getBehaviour() in BottomSheetDialogFragment

Answer (score 0):

```
BottomSheetDialog dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(this);
.
.
.
dialog.getBehavior().setPeekHeight(100);
```

This way you can set the bottom sheet dialog peek height without doing anything else.