# BottomSheetDialogFragment - How to set expanded height (or min top offset)

Tags: android, android-support-library, androiddesignsupport, bottom-sheet

I create a `BottomSheetDialogFragment` and I want to adjust it's maximum expanded height. How can I do that? I can retrieve the `BottomSheetBehaviour` but all I can find is a setter for the peek height but nothing for the expanded height.

```
public class DialogMediaDetails extends BottomSheetDialogFragment
{
    @Override
    public void setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style)
    {
        super.setupDialog(dialog, style);
        View view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.dialog_media_details, null);
        dialog.setContentView(view);

        ...

        View bottomSheet = dialog.findViewById(R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
        BottomSheetBehavior behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
        behavior.setPeekHeight(...);
        // how to set maximum expanded height???? Or a minimum top offset?

    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Why do I need that? Because I show a `BottomSheet` Dialog in a full screen activity and it looks bad if the `BottomSheet` leaves a space on top...

Comment: I am interested in knowing that **how can I set `max height` for `modal bottom sheet``**. I need my modal bottom sheet to go till half screen only and never till top even after dragging...Any clues?

Comment: @abat Hope it will helps : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53791225/1318946

Comment: @eRaisedToX You can also try : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53791225/1318946

Answer (score 48):

The height is being wrapped because the inflated view is added to the FrameLayout which has `layout_height=wrap_content`. See FrameLayout (R.id.design_bottom_sheet) at https://github.com/dandar3/android-support-design/blob/master/res/layout/design_bottom_sheet_dialog.xml.

The class below makes the bottom sheet full screen, background transparent, and fully expanded to the top.

```
public class FullScreenBottomSheetDialogFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {


    @CallSuper
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Dialog dialog = getDialog();

        if (dialog != null) {
            View bottomSheet = dialog.findViewById(R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
            bottomSheet.getLayoutParams().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        }
        View view = getView();
        view.post(() -> {
            View parent = (View) view.getParent();
            CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) (parent).getLayoutParams();
            CoordinatorLayout.Behavior behavior = params.getBehavior();
            BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior = (BottomSheetBehavior) behavior;
            bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(view.getMeasuredHeight());
            ((View)bottomSheet.getParent()).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)

        });
    }

}
```

--- EDIT Aug 30, 2018 ---
I realized a year later that the background was colored on the wrong view. This dragged the background along with the content while a user was dragging the dialog.
I fixed it so that the parent view of the bottom sheet is colored.

Comment: with androidX use:
`dialog?.findViewById<View>(
                com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet
            )`

Comment: can someone explain why the find bottom sheet view doesn't seem to work from `onCreateDialog` or `onViewCreated`?

Comment: `View bottomSheet = dialog.findViewById(R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
            bottomSheet.getLayoutParams().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;` This is what I am looking for

Answer (score 37):

I found a much simpler answer; in your example where you obtain the FrameLayout for the bottom sheet using this code

```
View bottomSheet = dialog.findViewById(R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
```

you can then set the height on the layout params for that View to whatever height you want to set the expanded height to.

```
bottomSheet.getLayoutParams().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
```

Comment: with androidX use:
`dialog?.findViewById<View>(
                com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet
            )`

Comment: one thing I noticed, this works, only when the parent layout of our bottomsheet is RelativeLayout

Answer (score 26):

**BIG UPDATE**
Avoiding duplicated code I'm giving a link to the [full answer](https://github.com/miguelhincapie/CustomBottomSheetBehavior) in where you can find all the explanations about how to get full behavior like Google Maps.

---

> I want to adjust its maximum expanded height. How can I do that?

Both `BottomSheet` and `BottomSheetDialogFragment` use a BottomSheetBehavior that you can found in Support Library 23.x

That Java class has 2 different uses for `mMinOffset`, one of them is used to define the area of the parent it will use to draw his content (maybe a `NestedScrollView`). And the other use is for defining the expanded anchor point, I mean, if you slide it up to form `STATE_COLLAPSED`it will animate your `BottomSheet`until he reached this anchor point BUT if you can still keep sliding up to cover all parent height (CoordiantorLayout Height).

If you took a look at `BottomSheetDialog` you will see this method:

```
private View wrapInBottomSheet(int layoutResId, View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
    final CoordinatorLayout coordinator = (CoordinatorLayout) View.inflate(getContext(),
            android.support.design.R.layout.design_bottom_sheet_dialog, null);
    if (layoutResId != 0 && view == null) {
        view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResId, coordinator, false);
    }
    FrameLayout bottomSheet = (FrameLayout) coordinator.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
    BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet).setBottomSheetCallback(mBottomSheetCallback);
    if (params == null) {
        bottomSheet.addView(view);
    } else {
        bottomSheet.addView(view, params);
    }
    // We treat the CoordinatorLayout as outside the dialog though it is technically inside
    if (shouldWindowCloseOnTouchOutside()) {
        final View finalView = view;
        coordinator.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (isShowing() &&
                        MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event) == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP &&
                        !coordinator.isPointInChildBounds(finalView,
                                (int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY())) {
                    cancel();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    return coordinator;
}
```

No idea which one of those 2 behaviors you want but if you need the second one follow those steps:

1. Create a Java class and extend it from `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<V>`
2. Copy paste code from the default `BottomSheetBehavior`  file to your new one.
3. Modify the method `clampViewPositionVertical` with the following code:

   ```
   @Override
   public int clampViewPositionVertical(View child, int top, int dy) {
       return constrain(top, mMinOffset, mHideable ? mParentHeight : mMaxOffset);
   }
   int constrain(int amount, int low, int high) {
       return amount < low ? low : (amount > high ? high : amount);
   }
   ```
4. Add a new state

   ```
   public static final int STATE_ANCHOR_POINT = X;
   ```
5. Modify the next methods: `onLayoutChild`, `onStopNestedScroll`, `BottomSheetBehavior<V> from(V view)` and `setState` (optional)

**And here is how it looks like**
[[image: CustomBottomSheetBehavior]]

Answer (score 23):

Its works for me. Add code on BottomSheetDialogFragment's onViewCreated() methode

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    view.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        override fun onGlobalLayout() {

            view.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)

            val dialog = dialog as BottomSheetDialog
            val bottomSheet = dialog.findViewById<View>(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet) as FrameLayout?
            val behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet!!)
            behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED

            val newHeight = activity?.window?.decorView?.measuredHeight
            val viewGroupLayoutParams = bottomSheet.layoutParams
            viewGroupLayoutParams.height = newHeight ?: 0
            bottomSheet.layoutParams = viewGroupLayoutParams
        }
    })
    dialogView = view
}
```

**Don't forget to remove viewTreeObserver.**

```
override fun onDestroyView() {
    dialogView?.viewTreeObserver?.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(null)
    super.onDestroyView()
}
```

Comment: Using `addOnGlobalLayoutListener` will cause screen flash, the main logic can be legal in `onViewCreated`

Comment: One thing I noticed, decorview is considering Navigation view height too, so any view aligned bottom of parent is cutting at the bottom, after replacing activity?.window?.decorView?.measuredHeight with height fetched in pixels using displaymetrics, worked for me

Answer (score 12):

Get reference to sheet behavior,

```
private val behavior by lazy { (dialog as BottomSheetDialog).behavior }
```

turn `fitToContents` off and set `expandedOffset` to desired pixels.

```
behavior.isFitToContents = false
behavior.expandedOffset = 100
```

Answer (score 5):

**Kotlin**

In my case I need to define a fixed height and I did the following:

```
val bottomSheet: View? = dialog.findViewById(R.id.design_bottom_sheet)
BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet!!).peekHeight = 250
```

this way you also have access to any property of the `BottomSheetBehavior` such as `halfExpandedRatio`

Answer (score 5):

I would advise against using ids to find views. In the `BottomSheetDialogFragment` the dialog is a `BottomSheetDialog` which exposes the behavior for the bottom sheet. You can use that to set the peek height.

```kotlin
(dialog as BottomSheetDialog).behavior.peekHeight = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what did the work for me in Kotlin (you can transit to Java easily):

In the onViewCreated() method of the Fragment, just put this code

```
 view.post {
        val parent = view.parent as View
        val behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(parent)
        val layoutParams = parent.layoutParams
        layoutParams.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        parent.layoutParams = layoutParams
        behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Jetpack Compose views inside `BottomSheetDialogFragment`, was not able to use `findViewById`, hence other answers were not proving to be helpful.

How I was able to use `setPeekHeight` was by overriding `onCreateDialog`:

```kotlin
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    val dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)
    dialog.setOnShowListener { dialogInterface ->
        val bottomSheetDialog = dialogInterface as? BottomSheetDialog
        bottomSheetDialog?.behavior?.setPeekHeight(3000)
    }
    return dialog
}
```