# Android: BottomSheetDialog does not expand completely with ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am using **ConstraintLayout** for my layout. I am creating a **BottomSheetDialog** and setting the layout to it which uses the **ConstraintLayout** at top.

> **Note:** If i use LinearLayout everything works fine and BottomSheetDialog takes proper height but when i am using
> ConstraintLayout, it shows only one option.

Please find the screenshot below when i am using ConstraintLayout:

[image]

My xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_other_methods"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ripple"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/dp_12"
        android:text="@string/from_other_methods"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="@dimen/sp_17" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_other_methods"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dip_1"
        android:background="@color/light_grey"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tv_other_methods" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_FromChinaUnionPay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ripple"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/dp_12"
        android:text="@string/from_china_union_pay"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="@dimen/sp_17"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/view_other_methods"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/view_FromChinaUnionPay" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_FromChinaUnionPay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dip_1"
        android:background="@color/light_grey"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tv_FromChinaUnionPay" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_Cancel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ripple"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/dp_12"
        android:text="@string/cancel"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="@dimen/sp_17"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view_FromChinaUnionPay" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

My java code for BottomSheetDialog:

```
final BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(mContext);
            bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_web_view_options);
            // dialog.setCancelable(false);
            final Window window = bottomSheetDialog.getWindow();
            assert window != null;
            window.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            window.setLayout(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
            window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
            window.getDecorView().setPadding(20, 0, 20, 0);

            bottomSheetDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
                @Override
                public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    FrameLayout bottomSheet = bottomSheetDialog.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
                    BottomSheetBehavior behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
                    behavior.setSkipCollapsed(true);
                    behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
                }
            });
```

In my layout if i replace**ConstraintLayout** with **LinearLayout** then it works fine and takes full height. Please let me know if i am doing something wrong.

I have tried these solutions but nothing worked:

- [Set state of BottomSheetDialogFragment to expanded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35937453/set-state-of-bottomsheetdialogfragment-to-expanded)
- [BottomSheetDialogFragment - How to set expanded height (or min top offset)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36030879/bottomsheetdialogfragment-how-to-set-expanded-height-or-min-top-offset)
- [Android BottomSheetDialogFragment does not expand completely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37555403/android-bottomsheetdialogfragment-does-not-expand-completely/38873329)

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why -1. If someone is giving down vote he/she must explain why, so i can learn whats wrong in my question and improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't constrained all the views - the first `TextView` has no constraints whatsoever . The constraints you added aren't properly specified to correctly display the views in vertical order. I suggest creating a vertical chain of all the views with the parent `ConstraintLayout's` `layout_height` set to `wrap_content`. The XML should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_other_methods"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ripple"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/dp_12"
        android:text="@string/from_other_methods"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="@dimen/sp_17"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopmOf="@id/view_other_methods"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_other_methods"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dip_1"
        android:background="@color/light_grey"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tv_FromChinaUnionPay"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_other_methods" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_FromChinaUnionPay"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ripple"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/dp_12"
        android:text="@string/from_china_union_pay"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="@dimen/sp_17"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/view_FromChinaUnionPay"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view_other_methods" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_FromChinaUnionPay"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dip_1"
        android:background="@color/light_grey"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tv_Cancel"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_FromChinaUnionPay" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_Cancel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ripple"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/dp_12"
        android:text="@string/cancel"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="@dimen/sp_17"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view_FromChinaUnionPay"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

As a side note, it is not advised to use `match_parent` for any views inside a `ConstraintLayout` as the documentation suggests:

> Important: MATCH_PARENT is not recommended for widgets contained in a ConstraintLayout. Similar behavior can be defined by using MATCH_CONSTRAINT with the corresponding left/right or top/bottom constraints being set to "parent".