# Creating a slideUp window over the main activity if a button is clicked

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I want to create a window which pops up when a button is clicked, in which I can give some buttons to be selected which can be used to provide some data to the main activity.

I tried with Dialog box and Frame layout. Problem with Dialog box is that it doesn't cover the whole screen. Problem with Frame layout using fragment transaction which I am facing is that the main activity's layout is also visible when frame layout comes into picture.

Eg.

[image]

But when i click on button to show the window from below:

[image]

ie. the image and START button from the activity is also visible. It should partially cover the activity with my fragment window I have tried with giving background color as white in FrameLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already tried with a `Dialog`, so maybe `BottomSheetDialogFragment` is a good choice for you since it extends from `DialogFragment`.

There is a Medium blog post with a short example: [Using BottomSheetDialogFragment with Material Design Guideline](https://medium.com/@kosta.palash/using-bottomsheetdialogfragment-with-material-design-guideline-f9814c39b9fc)

Since you need a fullscreen `Dialog`: [BottomSheetDialogFragment - How to set expanded height (or min top offset)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36030879/bottomsheetdialogfragment-how-to-set-expanded-height-or-min-top-offset) is an SO post about setting the expanded height of a `BottomSheetDialogFragment`.

See also the material design guidelines on [Modal Bottom Sheets](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-sheet-dialog-fragment/) as well as the [reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetDialogFragment)

Answer (score 1):

You can use bottom sheet.

Please find below tutorial link that will help you

[Android Bpttom sheet medium](https://medium.com/@droidbyme/android-bottom-sheet-7e9cfcec6427)

[Android Bottom sheet mindcor](https://blog.mindorks.com/android-bottomsheet-in-kotlin)

Let me know, Is it helping you or not +1

Comment: can i pass data from bottom sheet to main activity? Like what button or values were clicked in the sheet, and those values can i send it to main activity?

Comment: @TusharSeth : Yes

Comment: Thanks Hardik . This really helped me .. But Since 0x0nosugar explained well, so I am accepting his answer, but really appreciate as you were first to give this hint +1 for this

Answer (score 1):

Try this way of code to show the window

```
public void showDefaultDialog() {
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog);
     dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
     dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.animWindow;
     dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialogview);
     dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.WHITE));
     dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,   ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
}
```

put the below line of code in style.xml file

```
 <style name="animWindow">
     <item name="@android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/bottom_to_top</item>
     <item name="@android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/top_to_bottom</item>
</style>
```

put the below line of code in drawable folder

*- bottom_to_top.xml*

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <translate 
         android:fromYDelta="100%p"
         android:toYDelta="0%p"
         android:fillAfter="true"
         android:duration="700" />
     </set>
```

*- top_to_bottom.xml*

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <translate 
         android:fromYDelta="0%p"
         android:toYDelta="100%p"
         android:fillAfter="true"
         android:duration="700" />
     </set>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but BottomSheetNavigator is the simplest way to go for this hence accepted that answer , but +1 for using animation to do this