# Android BottomSheetDialogFragment does not expand completely

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, android-support-design, bottom-sheet

I have the following test bottom sheet implementation.

When I set the peekHeight to a value less than 500, it works. After some value, any increase in peek height will not change how the bottom sheet is expanded. It Just remains there to only drag manually. How do we set the peekHeight programmatically to ensure that the bottom sheet is auto expanded to the peek height.

[image]

**bottom_sheet_dialog_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/locUXCoordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/locUXView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:behavior_hideable="false"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="1 Value" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="2 Value" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="3 Value" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="4 Value" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="5 Value" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="6 Value" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="7 Value" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="8 Value" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="9 Value" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="First Value" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Java code**

```
public class MyBottomSheetDialogFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    private static BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior;
    private static View bottomSheetInternal;
    private static MyBottomSheetDialogFragment INSTANCE;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getDialog().setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                BottomSheetDialog d = (BottomSheetDialog) dialog;
                CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout)d.findViewById(R.id.locUXCoordinatorLayout);
                bottomSheetInternal = d.findViewById(R.id.locUXView);
                bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheetInternal);
                bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(bottomSheetInternal.getHeight());
                bottomSheetInternal.requestLayout();
                coordinatorLayout.getLayoutParams().height = bottomSheetInternal.getHeight();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Height is" + bottomSheetInternal.getHeight() + "  " + coordinatorLayout.getLayoutParams().height, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
        INSTANCE = this;
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_dialog_main, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: You do realize that the peek height is the height of the sheet being "collapsed" and just showing some of it? If you set the peek height to the height of the sheet itself (or bigger)...then the whole "peeking" is useless. Could you maybe explain *what* you are trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for that. Yes I realized that the peekHeight was set for a collapsed view. Anyways, I was able to correct the issue

Comment: this line made a trick for me: coordinatorLayout.getLayoutParams().height = bottomSheetInternal.getHeight();"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By deeper UI inspection, we find that there is another `CoordinatorLayout` that wraps our coordinator layout. The parent `CoordinatorLayout` has a `FrameLayout` with a `BottomSheetBehavior`with the id `design_bottom_sheet`. The peek height set from our code above was getting constrained due the `match_parent` height of the `FrameLayout` with the id `design_bottom_sheet`

By setting the peek height of the `FrameLayout` with the id design_bottom_sheet , this issue was resolved

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getDialog().setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            BottomSheetDialog d = (BottomSheetDialog) dialog;
            coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) d.findViewById(R.id.locUXCoordinatorLayout);
            bottomSheetInternal = d.findViewById(R.id.locUXView);
            bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheetInternal);
            bottomSheetBehavior.setHidable(false);
            BottomSheetBehavior.from((View)coordinatorLayout.getParent()).setPeekHeight(bottomSheetInternal.getHeight());
            bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(bottomSheetInternal.getHeight());
            coordinatorLayout.getParent().requestLayout();

        }
    });
```

Comment: This solution is giving errors in R.id.locUXCoordinatorLayout, Cannot resolve symbol. Which R we have to use here..?

Comment: locUXCoordinatorLayout , this was the id I had in my view. You may not have it in your view. See the code I have attached in the question. If if solves your problem, appreciate if you upvote the answer

Answer (score 44):

Using this code in onCreateView.

```
getDialog().setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            BottomSheetDialog d = (BottomSheetDialog) dialog;
            FrameLayout bottomSheet = (FrameLayout) d.findViewById(R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
            CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) bottomSheet.getParent();
            BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
            bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(bottomSheet.getHeight());
            coordinatorLayout.getParent().requestLayout();
        }
    });
```

Comment: In my case, these code should be called in `onActivityCreated` then work perfectly

Comment: Nice solution worked with me, I put the code in `onViewCreated()`

Answer (score 21):

I've found another solution. Maybe for future readers it can be useful.

```
@Override
public void setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style) {
    super.setupDialog(dialog, style);
    final View root = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.fragment_bottom_sheet_choose_time, null);
    dialog.setContentView(root);
    initView(root);

    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) ((View) root.getParent()).getLayoutParams();
    CoordinatorLayout.Behavior behavior = params.getBehavior();

    if (behavior != null && behavior instanceof BottomSheetBehavior) {
        mBottomSheetBehavior = (BottomSheetBehavior) behavior;
        mBottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback);

        root.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                root.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                int height = root.getMeasuredHeight();
                mBottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(height);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As @Anthonyeef mentioned, here `ViewTreeObserver` is aimed to get the exact measure height after the view is really measured and the `GlobalOnLayoutListener` is removed for better performance.

But please, before using in production, test this solution on different devices and screens, because if your content in bottom sheet is higher than your screen it can produce some strange swipe behavior.

Comment: This answer really solve my problem. If there could be some more explain, that would be nice. For example, I search around and test it myself, finnally figure out that ViewTreeObserver is aimed to get the exact measure height after the view is really measure, and the GlobalOnLayoutListener is removed for better performance.

Comment: I'm getting a few crash reports where the cast to CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams fails. It seems that on some devices in some situations, view.getParent() returns a LinearLayout instead of a CoordinatorLayout. Right now the crash reports are only for some Android 8.0 devices.

Comment: What is the difference between `setupDailog` and  `onCreateDialog`?

Answer (score 18):

**Kotlin** safe way of achieving this is:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    dialog.setOnShowListener {
        val dialog = it as BottomSheetDialog
        val bottomSheet = dialog.findViewById<View>(R.id.design_bottom_sheet)
        bottomSheet?.let { sheet ->
            dialog.behavior.peekHeight = sheet.height
            sheet.parent.parent.requestLayout()
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** No need to wrap your layout in coordinator layout.

Works like charm.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks @athysirus for the neat approach. Here is the version I ended up with, in case somebody wants to have a working kotlin sample.

Important to note is, that you should also remove the global layout listener, once done.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    view.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
            val bottomSheet = (dialog as BottomSheetDialog).findViewById<View>(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet)
            BottomSheetBehavior.from<View>(bottomSheet).apply {
                state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
                peekHeight = 0
            }
            view.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
        }
    })
```

Comment: But this solution creates another problem - after interactively moving the BottomSheetDialog down the background window remains darkened.

Comment: Yes, it remains darkened

Answer (score 1):

Solution in Kotlin inspired by [Nandish A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/651714/nandish-a)'s post in more detail. First the layout:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:behavior_hideable="false"
            app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

                  <!-- content of the bottom sheet -->

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And then put this into your `BottomSheetDialogFragment`:

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        // ...        

        dialog.setOnShowListener {

            val root = dialog.find<CoordinatorLayout>(R.id.container_root)
            val bottomSheetInternal = root.find<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.bottom_sheet)

            val bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheetInternal)
            bottomSheetBehavior.isHideable = false
            BottomSheetBehavior.from(root.parent as View).peekHeight = root.height
            bottomSheetBehavior.peekHeight = root.height
            root.parent.requestLayout()
        }

        // ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

this is how I set `peek_height` and `layout_height` to bottom sheet view in `BottomSheetDialogFragment`

```
dialog?.setOnShowListener {
                val dialog = dialog as BottomSheetDialog
                val bottomSheet = dialog.findViewById<FrameLayout>(R.id.design_bottom_sheet)
                val coordinatorLayout = bottomSheet?.parent as? CoordinatorLayout
                val bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet)
                bottomSheet?.viewTreeObserver?.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
                    bottomSheet.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener {}
                    bottomSheetBehavior.peekHeight = getPopupHeight(.5f)
                    val params = bottomSheet.layoutParams
                    params.height = getPopupHeight(1f)
                    bottomSheet.layoutParams = params
                    coordinatorLayout?.parent?.requestLayout()
                }
            }
```

this method to get percent of screen height

```
 private fun getPopupHeight(percent: Float): Int {
        val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
        activity?.windowManager?.defaultDisplay?.getMetrics(displayMetrics)
        return (displayMetrics.heightPixels * percent).toInt()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This made the trick for me! My class extends the BottomSheetDialogFragment

```
@Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    Dialog dialog = getDialog();

    if (dialog != null)
    {
        View bottomSheet = dialog.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);
        bottomSheet.getLayoutParams().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    }
    View view = getView();
    view.post(() -> {
        View bottomSheet = dialog.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);
        View parent = (View) view.getParent();
        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) (parent).getLayoutParams();
        CoordinatorLayout.Behavior behavior = params.getBehavior();
        BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior = (BottomSheetBehavior) behavior;
        bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(view.getMeasuredHeight());
        ((View) bottomSheet.getParent()).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    });
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_delivery_type, container, false);

    getDialog().setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog)
        {
            BottomSheetDialog d = (BottomSheetDialog) dialog;
            FrameLayout bottomSheet = (FrameLayout) d.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);
            CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) bottomSheet.getParent();
            BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
            bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(bottomSheet.getHeight());
            bottomSheetBehavior.setFitToContents(true);
            bottomSheetBehavior.setExpandedOffset(0);
            bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
            coordinatorLayout.getParent().requestLayout();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is combination of answers. Because some of them don't works for me correct.

In XML ids.xml:

```
<item name="sheet_parent_container" type="id" />
```

In XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@id/sheet_parent_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">

    **Dialog content here!**

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In BottomSheetDialogFragment.kt:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    ...

    setPeekHeight(view)
}

/**
 * Function for disable half height display after screen rotation.
 */
private fun setPeekHeight(view: View) {
    val parentContainer = view.findViewById<CoordinatorLayout>(R.id.sheet_parent_container)

    dialog?.setOnShowListener {
        val dialogParent = parentContainer.parent as View
        BottomSheetBehavior.from(dialogParent).peekHeight = parentContainer.height
        dialogParent.requestLayout()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just call `setFitToContents(true)` method on `BottomSheetBehavior` to make it not expand fully and its height will be equal to the height of you bottom sheet layout. Be sure that your layout is height is set to `wrap_content`.

Answer (score 0):

By using BottomSheetCallback like this :

```
class MyBottomSheetDialogFragment() : BottomSheetCallback() { 
    private val bottomSheetBehavior: BottomSheetBehavior<ConstraintLayout>

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(binding.bottomSheet)
        bottomSheetBehavior.addBottomSheetCallback(this)
    }

    override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
        val slideOffset: Float = bottomSheetBehavior.calculateSlideOffset()
        if (newState == STATE_EXPANDED && slideOffset < 1f) {
            // Enforce to expand the bottom sheet fully.
            bottomSheetBehavior.halfExpandedRatio = slideOffset
            bottomSheetBehavior.state = STATE_HALF_EXPANDED
            bottomSheetBehavior.state = STATE_EXPANDED
        }
    }

    override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {
        if (slideOffset > 1f) {
            // Reduce the height of the expanded bottom sheet.
            bottomSheetBehavior.halfExpandedRatio = BOTTOM_SHEET_SLIDE_OFFSET_ALMOST_FULL
            bottomSheetBehavior.state = STATE_HALF_EXPANDED
            bottomSheetBehavior.state = STATE_EXPANDED
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val BOTTOM_SHEET_SLIDE_OFFSET_ALMOST_FULL = 0.9f
    }
}
```