# how to show full layout in BottomSheetDialog with min and max height 350dp in android

Tags: java, android

My layout_xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/_350sdp"
    android:maxHeight="@dimen/_500sdp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/commentProblemScreenLL">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/commentProblemLV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/commentProblemNotFound"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/commentProblemNotFoundTV"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/m1dp"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/commentEditTextET"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"
            android:background="@null"
            android:hint="@string/comment_EditText"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/hintcolor" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/commentSendTextIB"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_4sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/cm_chat_send"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Java code:-

```
private void showCommentDailog()
   {
       Log.d(TAG,"showCommentDailog enter()");
       commentDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(getContext());
       View view = ((ProblemsDetailActivity) getActivity()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.commentproblemscreen, null);
       commentDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
       commentProblemLV = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.commentProblemLV);
       TextView commentProblemNotFoundTV = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.commentProblemNotFoundTV);
       EditText commentEditTextET = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.commentEditTextET);
       ImageButton commentSendTextIB = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.commentSendTextIB);
       if(commentDialog.getWindow() != null) {
           commentDialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
       }
       //call the function to show list of previous work
       commentDialog.setContentView(view);
       commentDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
       commentDialog.show();
       final BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from((View) view.getParent());


       bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
           @Override
           public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
               if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
                   commentDialog.dismiss();
               }else{
                   if (newState != BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
                       if(commentProblemLV != null && !listIsAtTop()){
                           bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
                       }
                   }
               }
           }

           @Override
           public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

           }

       });
   }
```

This code does not show the full layout in `bottomsheetDailog`. Please correct my code as it shows the full layout in `bottomsheetDialog`.
I want to open full layout in half screen with `BottomSheetDialog`.
here I should be given my java code also for `bottomSheetDialog`.
`bottomsheetdailog` will apear on clickof comment `ImageView`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37555403/android-bottomsheetdialogfragment-does-not-expand-completely/38873329

Comment: Here is explanation of the BottomSheet https://medium.com/@nullthemall/new-bottomsheet-caab21aff19b

Comment: I dont think you can show full screen BottomSheetDialog, it will only open with maximum allowed hight when it appearsm which is managed by this class. If you have specific requirement, try BottomSheetLayout