# BottomSheetDialogFragment has bottom part of it cut off when created

Tags: android, android-bottomsheetdialog

[image]

I'm using a BottomSheetDialogFragment however when I show it, part of it is being cut off at the bottom.
Why isn't it fully inflating and how can I fix this?

Heres the full layout and usage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fragplaces_app_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="12dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:text="test"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background_top_round_corners_blue"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/fragnearme_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fragplaces_app_name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/send_msg_layout"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/send_msg_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_emoji"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_grey_smiley_24dp"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/challengeroom_et_sendmessage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/btn_emoji"
            android:background="@drawable/background_chat_send_message"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:hint="Type a message"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:textColorHint="@color/defaultTextColor"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>


    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Usage:

```
BottomSheetDialogFragment chatFragment = new ChatFragment();
chatFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), Constants.FRAGMENT_CHAT);
```

I've tried changing the parent constraint layout height to `match_parent` and have also tried setting it to a defined height like 500dp, however it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `<item name="behavior_peekHeight">500dp</item>` in my BottomSheetDialog's style fixed the issue.

```
<style name="BottomSheetRoundedCorners" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_top_round_corners</item>
        <item name="behavior_peekHeight">500dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppBottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/BottomSheetRoundedCorners</item>
        <item name="behavior_draggable">false</item>

    </style>
```

and using it in my main app theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/AppBottomSheetDialogTheme</item>
</style>
```

Credits to this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35720641/11110509